# Child windows can't be maximized in Electron in GNU+Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, electron

I am writing a program in Electron. I have a parent window which creates child windows. My problem is that it is not possible to maximize the child windows.
I have read in [Electron Doc](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/) that the option `maximizable` is default true, but not implemented in Linux.

> `maximizable` Boolean - Whether window is maximizable. This is not implemented on Linux. Default is true.

Aparently, the default true does only apply to non-child windows and is default false at child windows.
The method `win.setMaximizable(true)` is not implemented in Linux either.

> `win.setMaximizable(maximizable)` `macOS Windows`
>
> ```
> maximizable Boolean
> ```
>
> Sets whether the window can be manually maximized by user. On Linux
>   does nothing.

I have also tried the method `win.maximize()` which is implemented but it didn't work as well, probably because the option maximizable is set to false.

> `win.maximize()`
>   Maximizes the window

Is there an other way to make these windows maximizable?

Comment: Perhaps you can look up the max width and height and change the windows to those values.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I see this question almost a year late, You probably already figure out a way to solve this, but just so you know, on Windows you can just "win.maximize()" to do this task, but on mac and Linux it is also required to set "win.resizable = true" otherwise it wont maximize the window, it will only set the bounds to the left corner of the screen, hope this helps at all, good luck!